# Stack wrap_content all the Widget inside?

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, stacklayout

I have a Widget tree like this:

```
  Stack(
    children: [
      Text(
        '-',
        style: title,
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'FT',
            style: normal,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

I want the Stack to wrap_content both width and height to all the widget inside it like this:

[image: Expectation]

But instead it look like this:

[image: Reality]

The Stack get the width and height from the un-fill Widget.
If I wrap both Widget in Positioned.fill then the layout is empty.
Any one know how to fix this? tks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alignment` property of `Stack` widget

Try this

```
     Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [

              Text(
                'GAME',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              Text(
                '  -  ',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html):

> The stack sizes itself to contain all the non-positioned children

So based on that we need to use a non-positioned child, though it still can be aligned with `Align` or an equivalent like `Center`.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Center(
      child: Text(
        '  -  ',
      ),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text(
        'FT',
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```